# XML querying date range lookup

Tags: javascript, php, xml, json, date

i have blocks XML list videos by date.

```
<item>
    <id>57376</id>
    <starttime>2015-02-16 20:00:00</starttime>
    <endtime>2015-02-16 21:00:00</endtime>
    <min>60</min>
    <vid>stream-20-16022015.mp4</vid>
</item>
```

i would like to lookup video file name by date hour min. what is best way to do it without involving SQL heavy languages. preferable JS or php?

Comment: like SELECT 1 VIDEO WHERE TIME = 2015-02-16 20:32

Comment: look up simplexml and xpath

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how i did it

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var vidlist = <?=json_encode($xml)?>;
  var playlist = [];

  $.each(vidlist.channel.item, function(i, v) {         
    playlist.push({file : v.vid, image : v.img, title : v.starttime});
  });

    function loadvid(){
        $.each(vidlist.channel.item, function(i, v) {
            var st = new Date(v.starttime);
            var et = new Date(v.endtime);
            var ck = new Date( $("#check").val() );
            if (ck >= st && ck < et) {
                jwplayer('myPlayer').onPlaylistItem(  function(event){ this.seek(ck.getMinutes()*60); }  ).playlistItem(i);
                return;
            }
        });
    }
</script>

<input type="text" id="check" value="2015-02-16 03:25:00" />
<button onclick="loadvid()">Load</button>
```